# 'list' object has no attribute 'map' in pyspark error

Tags: pyspark

""" df = sc.textFile("/content/Shakespeare.txt")

```
 llist = df.collect()
 for line in llist:
  t= simple_tokenize(line)     
  rdd2 = t.map(lambda word: (word,1))        # error on this line
  rdd3 = rdd2.reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a+b)
```

"""

I am facing an error on rdd2. Can someone please help?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and share your error traceback?

Comment: what is the output of `simple_tokenize`? FYI - once collected, the data is converted to list of objects, not an RDD.

Comment: If you would like to operate on the dataframe/rdd you would not collect it. Collect moves everything to the driver and would kill your driver if you have a large file.
If you want to operate on a dataframe with rdd functions you would do df.rdd.map...

Answer (score 0):

I think you would like a simple word count using rdd. You can do it by

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkFiles

# read file from url
url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brunoklein99/deep-learning-notes/master/shakespeare.txt"
spark.sparkContext.addFile(url)

df=spark.read.csv(SparkFiles.get("shakespeare.txt"), header=True)

df.show(4)
+------------------------------------------+
|THE SONNETS                               |
+------------------------------------------+
|by William Shakespeare                    |
|From fairest creatures we desire increase |
|That thereby beauty's rose might never die|
|But as the riper should by time decease   |
+------------------------------------------+
only showing top 4 rows

# convert to rdd taking only the strings of the row
rdd=df.rdd.map(lambda x: x["THE SONNETS"])
rdd.take(4)

['by William Shakespeare',
 'From fairest creatures we desire increase',
 "That thereby beauty's rose might never die",
 'But as the riper should by time decease']


# you can also parallelize a Python list of strings
data=["From fairest creatures we desire increase",
    "That thereby beauty's rose might never die",
    "But as the riper should by time decease",
    "His tender heir might bear his memory",
     ]
rdd=spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
```

Now run the basic three steps

1. split by words
2. count the words
3. reduce by key

```
rdd1=rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(" "))
rdd2=rdd1.map(lambda word: (word,1))
rdd3=rdd2.reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a+b)
rdd3.take(20)

[('by', 66),
 ('William', 1),
 ('Shakespeare', 1),
 ('From', 14),
 ('fairest', 5),
 ('creatures', 2),
 ('we', 11),
 ('desire', 6),
 ('increase', 3),
 ('That', 83),
 ('thereby', 1),
 ("beauty's", 16),
 ('rose', 5),
 ('might', 19),
 ('never', 10),
 ('die', 5),
 ('But', 89),
 ('as', 66),
 ('the', 311),
 ('riper', 2)]
```